# A question about binary series with recurrence relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, solution-verification

i need to calculate the amount of binary series without the appearance of the sequence 011.

I got to the answer $a_n = 2a_{n-1}-a_{n-3}$ by subtracting the option that this sequence appears. Is my solution right?

In the same question they ask also the amount of ternary series without the appearance of the sequences 02,20,22,00 (even numbers next to each other).

My solution is $a_n = a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$. Is it okay?

Comment: You did not define $n$.

Comment: How did you come to those recurrences? Oerhaps they are right, but your path to them totally wrong...